# Checar se campo preenchido automaticamente está "True" jQuery

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte campos

```
<input type="text" value="" name="campo" id="campo">
<input type="text" value="" name="campoRecebeDados" id="campoRecebeDados">
```

E o seguinte jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    function setar_valor(){
        var campo = $("#campo").val();
        $("#campoRecebeDados").val(campo);
    }

    $(document).on("keyup", "#campo", setar_valor);   

});
```

No momento estou usando `keyup`, que seria no caso se o `campo` for preenchido, ele copia o valor para o `campoRecebeDados`, mas como eu sei (via código) que o `campoRecebeDados` foi preenchido?

Pensei em fazer:

```
if($("#campoRecebeDados")==true){
    alert('Preenchido')
}
```

Porém, se eu fizer desta forma, ele nunca vai ser true, porque o preenchimento `value=""` do campo sempre será o estágio inicial, não o que foi setado. (isso se vermos no código fonte);

Neste caso eu já preenchi um campo anterior, que preencheu este, mas como podem ver o value="" permanece inalterado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aí você teria que alterar o atributo `value`, que é uma propriedade do input:

```
$("#campoRecebeDados").attr("value", campo);
```

O `.val()` não altera essa propriedade, ele apenas pega ou altera o que tem dentro do campo, e isso já é suficiente para saber se o campo foi ou não preenchido.

E para verificar se o input possui alguma coisa, bastaria:

```
if($("#campoRecebeDados").val()){
    // possui algum valor
}
```

No caso de inputs, se o `value` inicial for vazio, não precisa nem colocar `value=""`, porque o `value` já vem vazio por padrão.

Exemplo baseado no seu código:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    function setar_valor(){
        var campo = $("#campo").val();
        $("#campoRecebeDados").val(campo);

      if($("#campoRecebeDados").val()){
         console.log("tem valor");
      }else{
         console.log("não tem valor");
      }
    }

    $(document).on("keyup", "#campo", setar_valor);   

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo">
<input type="text" name="campoRecebeDados" id="campoRecebeDados">
```

Comment: Neste caso, eu precisava que a verificação fosse automatica.. ou seja, preencheu, ele passou pro outro campo e verifique automaticamente se o outro campo foi ou não preenchido...

Comment: Fiquei meio sem entender o objetivo, mas fiz uma alteração na resposta. Não sei se é isso que quer.

Answer (score 2):

Tente

```
if( $("#campoRecebeDados").val().length > 0 ){}
```

Ou

```
if( $("#campoRecebeDados").val() != "" ){}
```

Comment: O problema é que na o val dele nunca será o value setado através do jQuery, ele sempre ficará no estágio inicial. Que é o value=""